# Not getting data in onResponse in volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am not getting data in response in volley.
In my activity I have created method to get List.

PackageActivity.java

```
 private List<Package> preparePackageData() {
    MakeNetworkRequest data = new MakeNetworkRequest(PackageActivity.this);
    packageList = data.getAllPackage();
    return packageList;
}
```

Below is my MakeNetworkRequest.java

```
package com.lab.demo5;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.List;


public class MakeNetworkRequest{
    private static final String JSON_URL = "http://localhost/android/package.php";
    String response;
    Context context;
    private List<Package> packageList=null;

    MakeNetworkRequest(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context=ctx;
    }

    protected List<Package> getAllPackage()
    {
        Log.d("getAllPackage","getAllPackage");
        sendRequest();
        return this.packageList;
    }

    public void sendRequest(){

       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
               Log.d("onResponse","onResponse");
               showJSON(response);
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Toast.makeText(context,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String json){
        Log.d("showJSON","onResponse");
        ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
        pj.parseResult();
        this.packageList = pj.packageList;

    }
}
```

I am getting "getAllPackage" in log but it is not show any data in log "onResponse".

Whereas the same code give me good result when I am placing this code in directly in Activity.

Comment: Try using debugger to locate your error. On Android studio, you do this by putting a breakpoint and using `Ctrl + F9` buttons(or `Cmd + F9` for Mac). [Here's a simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo5PXWnKtQ4) for this.

Comment: yes,I debug the issue. its look like I am accessing data in Mainthread where as i am getting data in network thread in Volley. Now the question how to get data back in Main Thread. My call is like this.  PackageActivity has recyclerview which calls-> Network thread ->get data in List-->setRecyclerview adapter-> where i have null.

Comment: Because Volley execute task asynchronous with your thread, so take a delay time to see "onResponse" or an error if some things wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is caused by returning `this.packageList` from `getAllPackages()`. It returns `null` and you later changed the reference of `this.packageList` in `showJson()`.

Also, I suggest that you should implement callbacks instead of this. Like this:

```
protected void getAllPackage(@NonNull ResultListener listener);
```

and then calling back when on `onRespose()` is called, like `listener.onSuccess(data)`.

Also do note that you need to create the `SuccessListener` interface yourself. Something like this:

```
public interface ResultListener{
  onSuccess(List<Package> packages);
  onError(Exception exception);
}
```

By doing this, you can use this in your activity:

```
new MakeNetworkRequest(this).getAllPackages(new MakeNetworkRequest.ResultListener(){
  @Override 
  onSuccess(List<Package> packages){

  }
  @Override
  onError(Exception error){

  }
});
```

I have created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/underscoredam/27fb33f206a154164616b0aad683deb8).